# Uploading a picture to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload a image to a gallery on a facebook fan page, here is my code thus far,

```
$ch = curl_init();

        $data = array('type' => 'client_cred', 'client_id' => 'app_id','client_secret'=>'secret_key',' redirect_uri'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/my-application/'); // your connect url here

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        $rs = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $ch = curl_init();
        $data = explode("=",$rs);
        $token = $data[1];

        $album_id = '1234';
        $file= 'http://my.website.com/my-application/sketch.jpg';
        $data = array(basename($file) => "@".realpath($file),
        //filename, where $row['file_location'] is a file hosted on my server
            "caption" => "test",
            "aid" => $album_id, //valid aid, as demonstrated above
            "access_token" => $token
        );

        $ch2 = curl_init();
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$album_id."/photos";
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $op = curl_exec($ch2);
```

When I echo $token, I seem to be getting the token, but when I run the script, I get this error, {"error":{"type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","message":"An access token is required to request this resource."} , I have NO idea why it is doing this!

Basically what I am doing in that code is getting the access token with curl, and then, uploading the photo to my album also via curl, but I keep getting that error!

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, got it working, here is the code, assuming that you have a valid session going.

```
    $token = $session['access_token'];

    //upload photo
    $file= 'photo.jpg';
    $args = array(
    'message' => 'Photo from application',
    );
    $args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='.$token;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

This will upload the specified image to the session holders gallery, it will create a album if there is not one present, also you can access the token via the session array as demonstrated above.
Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: It's a pleasure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your application doesn't have needed permissions.

> To request permissions via OAuth, use
>   the scope argument in your
>   authorization request, and include a
>   comma separated list of all the
>   permissions you want to request.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: I am actually requesting the publish_stream permission in my session, but still nothing.

Comment: You post image to album, shouldn't you request user_photos too?

Comment: Good point, I'll try that! I'll keep you guys posted! Thanx for the comments thus far!