# Facebook Graph API - Photo Upload

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that uses the old Facebook API but now I'm migrating it. The application works good until I try to upload a photo.

I knew how to do it in the old way, but now... I'm in troubles.

This is the way I used to do it:

$args = array
    (
        'method'  => 'photos.upload',
        'v'       => $ver,
        'api_key' => $key,
        'uid'     => $uid,
        'call_id' => $cid,
        'format'  => 'XML',
        'caption' => $caption
    );

```
signRequest($args, $sec);
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=photos.upload';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're not using the new PHP SDK?

Comment: Take a look ah this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019501/uploading-a-picture-to-facebook

Comment: Totally correct dude,,, in fact I saw that post and give that guy me regrets but thank you also.

For the ones that don't know take a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019501/uploading-a-picture-to-facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:

[Uploading a picture to facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019501/uploading-a-picture-to-facebook)

There is shown how to use the new Facebook Graph API with the PHP Curl function and a valid session token.

Answer (score 0):

The API url starts with `https://` not `http://`. That could be the issue.